# Index max row size error

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-design, index, postgresql-9.1

Is there a upper bound for an `array` column?

I am getting this error when inserting into the array field -

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  index row size 3480 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "ix_data"
```

Here's my table definition -

```
create table test_array(id varchar(50), data text[]);

ALTER TABLE test_array ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX ix_data ON test_array USING GIN (data);
```

I need an index on array field, since I am doing some lookups on it.

Comment: Could it be that `data` contains a list of tags like demonstrated in this [related blog post by Scott Snyder](http://sjsnyder.com/using-postgresql-arrays-with-gin-indexes-for)? If that is the case, I might have a better solution for you.

Comment: user310525, I'd like to second Erwin's suggestion that this would be better on dba.se, if you are willing to create an account there and flag for a moderator to migrate?

Comment: Due to link rot: [archive.org link for Scott's blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130526042923/http://sjsnyder.com/using-postgresql-arrays-with-gin-indexes-for)

Answer (score 17):

#### The problem

Here is a [very similar case discussed on pgsql.general](https://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/SQL-index-row-size-2728-exceeds-btree-maximum-2713-td1844319.html). It's about the limitation in a b-tree index, but it's all the same because a GIN index uses a b-tree index for *keys* internally and therefore runs into the same limitation for *key* size (instead of *item* size in a plain b-tree index).

I quote the [manual about GIN index implementation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-implementation.html):

> Internally, a GIN index contains a B-tree index constructed over keys,
> where each key is an element of one or more indexed items

Either way, at least one **array element** in your column `data` is too big to be indexed. If this is just a singular freak value or some kind of accident you may be able to truncate the value and be done with it.

For the purpose of the following demo I'll assume otherwise: lots of long text values in the array.

#### Simple solution

You could replace elements in your array `data` with according *hash values*. And send look-up values through the same hash function. Of course, you probably want to store your originals in addition somewhere. With that, we almost arrive at my second variant ...

#### Advanced solution

You could create a look-up table for array elements with a `serial` column as surrogate primary key (effectively a radical kind of hash value) - which is all the more interesting if involved element values are not unique:

```
CREATE TABLE elem (
  elem_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, elem    text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Since we want to look up `elem`, we add an index - **but** an [index on an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) this time, with only the *first 10 characters* of the long text. That should be enough in most cases to narrow a search down to one or a few hits. Adapt the size to your data distribution. Or use a more sophisticated hash function.

```
CREATE INDEX elem_elem_left10_idx ON elem(left(elem,10));
```

Your column `data` would then be of type `int[]`. I renamed the table to `data` and got rid of the ominous `varchar(50)` in your example:

```
CREATE TABLE data(
  data_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, data int[]
);
```

Each array element in `data` refers to a `elem.elem_id`. At this point, you may consider to replace the array column with an n:m table, thereby normalizing your schema and allowing Postgres to enforce referential integrity. Indexing and general handling becomes easier ...

However, for performance reasons, the `int[]` column in combination with a GIN index may be superior. Storage size is *a lot* smaller. In this case we need the GIN index:

```
CREATE INDEX data_data_gin_idx ON data USING GIN (data);
```

Now, each *key* of the GIN index (= array element) is an `integer` instead of a longish `text`. The index will be smaller by several orders of magnitude, searches will consequently be *much* faster.

The downside: before you can actually perform a search you have to look up the `elem_id` from the table `elem`. Using my newly introduced functional index `elem_elem_left10_idx`, this, too, will be much faster.

You can do it **all in one simple query**:

```
SELECT d.*, e.*
FROM   elem e
JOIN   data d ON ARRAY[e.elem_id] <@ d.data
WHERE  left(e.elem, 10) = left('word1234word', 10) -- match index condition
AND    e.elem = 'word1234word';  -- need to recheck, functional index is lossy
```

You may be interested in the extension [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html), that supplies additional operators and operator classes.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6de74dfb50efaffc964ed568d1f098fb)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1b470/1)</sub>

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this on a PostGIS geography column. It was because I accidentally created the index incorrectly. You should include the USING GIST parameter when creating such indexes.

Comment: Thank you -- that was it! Wow, so far fetched. May have saved me hours. Especially since I thought GiST was used by default but I was mistaken and it tries to use b-tree.

Answer (score 2):

The error is with the index `ix_data`, not the `text[]` field. The maximum size for a row in that particular index type is limited to `2712` bytes. If you drop your index and try the insert again, it should work for you. If you need to index a larger field, you may want to look into the [full text indexing features](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Full_Text_Indexing_with_PostgreSQL) of Postgres.