# SELECT query with DISTINCT on a table-structure for graphs is very slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, postgresql-9.4

I have 2 tables where `nodes` contains about 60m rows and `edges` about 500m rows (both growing fast). These two tables represent a directed graph.

```
CREATE TABLE edges (
  node_from bigint NOT NULL,
  node_to bigint NOT NULL,
  prop bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX edges_prop_idx   ON edges (prop);
CREATE INDEX from_prop_idx    ON edges (node_from, prop);
CREATE INDEX from_to_prop_idx ON edges (node_from, node_to, prop);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
  name text,
  type text NOT NULL,
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT nodes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX name_idx          ON nodes ("substring"(name, 1, 2700));
CREATE INDEX trgm_gin_name_idx ON nodes USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

I have the following query:

```
SELECT nodes.id, nodes.name, nodes.type
FROM nodes
LEFT JOIN edges B1 ON 
    B1.node_to = nodes.id
LEFT JOIN edges A1 ON
    A1.node_to = B1.node_from
LEFT JOIN edges C1 ON
    C1.node_from = B1.node_to
WHERE
    B1.prop = (SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE substring(name, 1, 2700) = 'name' AND type = 'property')::bigint -- Property
    AND A1.prop = (SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE substring(name, 1, 2700) = '...' AND type = 'property')::bigint -- Property
    AND C1.prop = 2
    AND C1.node_to = ANY ((SELECT array(SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE substring(name, 1, 2700) = 'de'))::bigint[])
LIMIT 50
```

This query works so far (returns in <= 200ms) but returns a lot of duplicates. I would love to eliminate these duplicates and thought about adding a `DISTINCT ON (nodes.id)` to the query. Unfortunately, this leads to a never-ending query. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 (beta).

## Query plans

Without DISTINCT:

```
"Limit  (cost=39.55..111.62 rows=50 width=33)"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"    ->  Index Scan using name_idx on nodes nodes_1  (cost=0.57..12.61 rows=1 width=8)"
"          Index Cond: ("substring"(name, 1, 2700) = 'name'::text)"
"          Filter: (type = 'property'::text)"
"  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)"
"    ->  Index Scan using name_idx on nodes nodes_2  (cost=0.57..12.61 rows=1 width=8)"
"          Index Cond: ("substring"(name, 1, 2700) = '...'::text)"
"          Filter: (type = 'property'::text)"
"  InitPlan 4 (returns $3)"
"    ->  Result  (cost=12.60..12.61 rows=1 width=0)"
"          InitPlan 3 (returns $2)"
"            ->  Index Scan using name_idx on nodes nodes_3  (cost=0.57..12.60 rows=2 width=8)"
"                  Index Cond: ("substring"(name, 1, 2700) = 'de'::text)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.72..53798189845.30 rows=37322005381 width=33)"
"        Join Filter: (b1.node_to = c1.node_from)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..8489574975.42 rows=1038114946 width=41)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..128899706.72 rows=1038114946 width=8)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on edges a1  (cost=0.00..6963386.60 rows=1724439 width=8)"
"                          Filter: (prop = $1)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using from_prop_idx on edges b1  (cost=0.57..70.51 rows=20 width=16)"
"                          Index Cond: ((node_from = a1.node_to) AND (prop = $0))"
"              ->  Index Scan using nodes_pkey on nodes  (cost=0.56..8.04 rows=1 width=33)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = b1.node_to)"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using from_to_prop_idx on edges c1  (cost=0.58..43.63 rows=1 width=8)"
"              Index Cond: ((node_from = nodes.id) AND (node_to = ANY ($3)) AND (prop = 2))"
"Planning time: 1.790 ms"
```

With DISTINCT:

```
"Limit  (cost=7608487867.87..7608488177.20 rows=50 width=33)"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"    ->  Index Scan using name_idx on nodes nodes_1  (cost=0.57..12.61 rows=1 width=8)"
"          Index Cond: ("substring"(name, 1, 2700) = 'name'::text)"
"          Filter: (type = 'property'::text)"
"  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)"
"    ->  Index Scan using name_idx on nodes nodes_2  (cost=0.57..12.61 rows=1 width=8)"
"          Index Cond: ("substring"(name, 1, 2700) = '...'::text)"
"          Filter: (type = 'property'::text)"
"  InitPlan 4 (returns $3)"
"    ->  Result  (cost=12.60..12.61 rows=1 width=0)"
"          InitPlan 3 (returns $2)"
"            ->  Index Scan using name_idx on nodes nodes_3  (cost=0.57..12.60 rows=2 width=8)"
"                  Index Cond: ("substring"(name, 1, 2700) = 'de'::text)"
"  ->  Unique  (cost=7608487830.05..7981707883.86 rows=60328104 width=33)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=7608487830.05..7701792843.50 rows=37322005381 width=33)"
"              Sort Key: nodes.id, nodes.name, nodes.type"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=15672379.12..34349332.83 rows=37322005381 width=33)"
"                    Hash Cond: (b1.node_to = nodes.id)"
"                    ->  Merge Join  (cost=5419844.59..20186145.96 rows=1038114946 width=8)"
"                          Merge Cond: (b1.node_from = a1.node_to)"
"                          ->  Sort  (cost=2506073.10..2510384.20 rows=1724439 width=16)"
"                                Sort Key: b1.node_from"
"                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on edges b1  (cost=32280.97..2327441.09 rows=1724439 width=16)"
"                                      Recheck Cond: (prop = $0)"
"                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on edges_prop_idx  (cost=0.00..31849.86 rows=1724439 width=0)"
"                                            Index Cond: (prop = $0)"
"                          ->  Sort  (cost=2506073.10..2510384.20 rows=1724439 width=8)"
"                                Sort Key: a1.node_to"
"                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on edges a1  (cost=32280.97..2327441.09 rows=1724439 width=8)"
"                                      Recheck Cond: (prop = $1)"
"                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on edges_prop_idx  (cost=0.00..31849.86 rows=1724439 width=0)"
"                                            Index Cond: (prop = $1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=10251247.23..10251247.23 rows=102984 width=41)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3001857.14..10251247.23 rows=102984 width=41)"
"                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on edges c1  (cost=3001856.57..9416003.75 rows=102984 width=8)"
"                                      Recheck Cond: (prop = 2)"
"                                      Filter: (node_to = ANY ($3))"
"                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on edges_prop_idx  (cost=0.00..3001830.82 rows=162545367 width=0)"
"                                            Index Cond: (prop = 2)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using nodes_pkey on nodes  (cost=0.56..8.10 rows=1 width=33)"
"                                      Index Cond: (id = c1.node_from)"
"Planning time: 1.102 ms"
```

Any ideas on how I could optimize my query (with `DISTINCT`) to make it reasonably fast?

Comment: You'll probably need a (unique) index on `(name, type)`

Comment: If all else fails you can wrap the old query in a subquery with an `OFFSET 0` to prevent flattening, and then do the deduplication in an outer query. (Not saying that's the right way, it's just *a* way).

Comment: @ypercube: I just tried it. Unfortunately, this did not improve the speed. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry, did you add an index on `((substring(name,1,2700), type)` or just on `(name, type)`? Anyway, this was just a first glimpse on the (complicated) query. You don't seem to have any composite index with `node_to` as the first column and you might need one as well. This needs testing though, with real data, and possible rewritings of the query (say with `EXISTS` instead of joins.) I don't think it's something as simple as adding an index or two.

Comment: @ypercube: I did add an index on `((substring(name,1,2700), type)`. Yeah it's quite complex, I try adding more compound indexes with `node_to` as the first column. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Creating other compound indexes didn't helped either.

Comment: What can you tell us about `nodes.name`? What is the minimum / average / maximum length? What is stored? Do you ever need to sort rows by it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Table layout

- It would be more efficient to reverse the column order in `nodes`: fixed length `NOT NULL` columns first. This is just a tiny optimization. It's only the first item because table layout comes first.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE nodes(
     id bigint PRIMARY KEY
   , type text NOT NULL
   , name text
  );
  ```

#### Index

- Replace `substring(name,1,2700)` with `left(name, 2700)` everywhere, it's slightly faster and shorter. Better yet, don't use this *at all*. Consider the next point.
- An index on 2700 characters of text is very inefficient. Only 3 index entries will fit on a data page - or it won't work at all. If you have many multi-byte characters, the actual byte-size can be considerably bigger than 2700, which would result in an exception:

  - [Index max row size error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error)
  - [Character varying index overhead & length limit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69161/character-varying-index-overhead-length-limit/69164#69164)

  If you don't run into exceptions, the index is still going to be *huge* and relatively slow. If all you do is equality checks with the `=` operator, use a functional index on a hash value instead.
  And I would append the id to it to allow index-only scans:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX name_md5_idx ON nodes (md5(name), id);
  ```

  And adapt your queries to it.
- I don't see a PK on `edges`? Every table should have one.
- I don't see an index on `edges` with `node_to` as leading column. May or may not be needed:

  - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

### Query

Your `LEFT JOIN` clauses are counteracted by later conditions on the left tables. Use `[INNER] JOIN` instead. And adapt to the suggested functional index:

#### Step 1

```
SELECT n.id, n.name, n.type
FROM   nodes n
JOIN   edges B1 ON B1.node_to = n.id
JOIN   edges A1 ON A1.node_to = B1.node_from
JOIN   edges C1 ON C1.node_from = B1.node_to
WHERE  B1.prop = (SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE md5(name) = md5('name') AND type = 'property')
AND    A1.prop = (SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE md5(name) = md5('...')  AND type = 'property')
AND    C1.prop = 2
AND    C1.node_to = ANY (SELECT array(SELECT id FROM nodes WHERE md5('name') = md5('de')))
LIMIT  50;
```

#### Step 2

Untangle:

```
SELECT n.id, n.name, n.type
FROM   edges an
JOIN   nodes a  ON a.prop = an.id
JOIN   edges b  ON b.node_from = a.node_to
JOIN   nodes bn ON bn.id = b.prop
JOIN   edges c  ON c.node_from = b.node_to
JOIN   nodes cn ON cn.id = c.node_to
JOIN   nodes n  ON n.id = c.node_from
WHERE  md5(an.name) = md5('...')
AND    an.type = 'property'
AND    md5(bn.name) = md5('name')
AND    bn.type = 'property'
AND    c.prop = 2
AND    md5(cn.name) = md5('de')
LIMIT  50;
```

In particular, replace the sub-selects with more plain joins, thereby getting rid of the intermediary array (which is probably expensive).

If your `nodes` table grows fast enough that collisions in the md5 key space seem possible, add exact predicates to recheck (not expensive):

```
AND    an.name = '...'
AND    bn.name = 'name'
AND    cn.name = 'de'
```