# UNIQUE constraint on large VARCHARs - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, varchar, unique-constraint, index

I have a column defined like:

```
data_url character varying(32768) NOT NULL
```

and UNIQUE constraint on that column:

```
CONSTRAINT unique_data_url UNIQUE (data_url)
```

When a large object is being inserted into the table, the following error message appears:

> ```
> ERROR:  index row requires 32584 bytes, maximum size is 8191
> ```

How can PostgreSQL be set in order to be able to index object larger that 8191 chars? Space and speed are not a problem. It is a rarely changed table of at most hundreds of rows.

Environment: PostgreSQL 9.3.6, Fedora 20 x64

Comment: A common workaround is using something like `CONSTRAINT unique_data_url_hash UNIQUE (MD5(data_url))`

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As suggested by [@Josh Kupershmidt](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/31936/josh-kupershmidt) and [@JoeNahmias](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/36403/joenahmias) the solution is to use UNIQUE on md5 hash of the long value. However PostgreSQL 9.3 doesn't support expressions in [UNIQUE constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtable.html) so an **index**, that supports expressions, has to be used:

```sql
create unique index unique_data_url_index on mytable (md5(data_url));
```

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL builds an index to support the UNIQUE constraint.  You cannot index a field that large.  As @josh-kupershmidt suggested, create the constraint on a hash of the field and you should be alright, barring hash collisions.