# Which Index for WHERE UPPER("my_col"::text) LIKE "FOO" search on bytea

Tags: postgresql, bytea

I use the unusual bytea column type in a PostgreSQL DB because the data in this column is like a blob. I mostly contains text, but sometimes it contains binary data.

Which index would fit if the query like this gets done?

```
WHERE (UPPER("my_bytea_col"::text) LIKE '%FOO%'
```

Comment: Why do you compare the byte array with another column of your table? Or did you mean to write `LIKE 'FOO'` - which would be identical to `= 'FOO'`. But in general `create index on the_table ( (UPPER("my_bytea_col"::text) text_pattern_ops)` would be usable by LIKE. But you can't index column values that are bigger than approximately 2K - if your `bytea` column is bigger than that, you won't be able to insert rows containing data exceeding that limit

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am sorry. This was a typo. I updated the question. Yes, the column values will be bigger than 2K. Does the 2K limit apply to bytea only?

Comment: No, the 2k limit is a general restriction on the size of an index entry. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69161) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217087)

Comment: If the column can contain binary data, then the "my_bytea_col"::text inside the UPPER call is going to blow up.  So you have to decide, is it binary or is it not?

Comment: Actually it won't blow up, it just won't produce meaningful results.

Comment: @jjanes is there a way to make a trigram indexing and ignore binary characters? If there is a word (for example "superfoo") in the binary, then it get indexes. If there are words with printable characters (with a length of three or more) then they get indexes. Non printable characters don't get indexes. Is something like this possible?

Comment: You could create a immutable function which changes \000 null characters (plus any other characters you consider to be binary) to spaces, then create a trigram index on that function over the column.  There might be such a function built in, but if so I don't know of it.

Comment: @jjanes if you write your comment as answer, then I can up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an immutable function which changes the \000 null characters (plus any other characters you consider to be binary) to spaces, then create a trigram index on that function over the column. There might be such a function built in, but if so I don't know of it.